# Start and end date from date range

Tags: sql-server

I have following date range:

```
06/28/2014
06/29/2014
06/30/2014
07/01/2014
07/02/2014
```

I want to find smallest and largest date from the given date range. In this case `06/28/2014` and `07/02/2014`, respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is answer, but next time try to find this easy answer by yourself:

```
DECLARE @datesTable TABLE (Dates DATE)


INSERT INTO @datesTable SELECT '06/28/2014'
INSERT INTO @datesTable SELECT '06/29/2014'
INSERT INTO @datesTable SELECT '06/30/2014'
INSERT INTO @datesTable SELECT '07/01/2014'
INSERT INTO @datesTable SELECT '07/02/2014'


SELECT MAX(Dates) AS MaxDate, MIN(Dates) AS MinDate
FROM @datesTable
```